# ASP.NET MVC Post data from view using controller method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Hope you peeps can help ill start with my problem.

Code Problem: 
Passing data entered from a completed user form, to a method in controller which posts values back to api, at same time a modal is loaded containing the submitted data.

My Issue:
Ive attempted to come up with a solution to the above problem but I don't think the post request is being sent after checking with firebug in firefox but I don't know why. The modal is displayed and values are shown within the body correctly.

Here is what i have so far:

Bootstrap Form:

```
<form action="/Home/PostData" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="imei">IMEI:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imei" name="formpart" placeholder="IMEI">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="formpart" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="platform" class="control-label col-xs-2">Policy Organisation:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span id="dropdown_title1">Select</span>
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdownMenu1">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">TMT Internals</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="policyNumber" class="control-label col-xs-2">Policy Number:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="policyNumber" name="formpart" placeholder="Policy Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="platform" class="control-label col-xs-2">Platform:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span id="dropdown_title2">Select</span>
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu2">
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Android</a></li>
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">IOS</a></li>
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Windows Phone</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="diagnosticMode" class="control-label col-xs-2">Diagnostic Mode:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span id="dropdown_title3">Select</span>
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdownMenu3">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Simple</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Advanced</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mannual</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Complete</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                            <button type="submit" id="SendRequest" class="btn btn-success">Create New Request</button>
                            <button  class="btn btn-primary">Back to List</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult PostData()
    {            
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            reqparm.Add("IMEI", Request["#imei"].ToString());
            reqparm.Add("PhoneNumber", Request["#phoneNumber"].ToString());
            reqparm.Add("PolicyNumber", Request["#policyNumber"].ToString());
            reqparm.Add("SupportUserId", Session["UserId"].ToString());
            reqparm.Add("PolicyOrganisationId", Request["#dropdown_title1"].ToString());
            reqparm.Add("PlatformFamilyInfoId", Request["#dropdown_title2"].ToString());
            reqparm.Add("AppModeId", Request["#dropdown_title3"].ToString());
            byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues("**removed url for security purposes**", "POST", reqparm);
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
        }
        return View("something");
    }
```

Jquery (passes values to modal)

```
    // captures user entered data
    $("#SendRequest").click(function () {
        var imei = ("IMEI: " + $("#imei").val());
        $('#printImei').html(imei);           

        var phonenumber = ("Phone Number: " + $("#phoneNumber").val());
        $('#printPhoneNumber').html(phonenumber);

        var policyorganisation = ("Organisation: " + $("#dropdown_title1").text());
        $('#printPolicyOrg').html(policyorganisation);

        var policynumber = ("Policy Number: " + $("#policyNumber").val());
        $('#printPolicyNumber').html(policynumber);

        var platform = ("Platform: " + $("#dropdown_title2").text());
        $('#printPlatform').html(platform);

        var diagmode = ("Diagnostic Mode: " + $("#dropdown_title3").text());
        $('#printDiagnosticMode').html(diagmode);
    });
```

Modal shown after "Create new Request" is clicked:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Summary</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <span id="printImei"></span><br />
                            <span id="printPhoneNumber"></span><br />
                            <span id="printPolicyOrg"></span><br />
                            <span id="printPolicyNumber"></span><br />
                            <span id="printPlatform"></span><br />
                            <span id="printDiagnosticMode"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: This is dreadful way to construct you view and post back data (have you heard of view models and html helpers). Controls post back values based on the `name` attribute of controls (not the `id` attribute) and all your `name` attributes are the same (`formpart`)

Comment: Yes I'm pretty new to mvc as a whole so this may not be the best way. All the name attributes are the same on purpose as they are all validated using $("[name='formpart']").each in JQuery(not shown above). Is this why the values are not being posted?

Comment: Yes. To test, change the the first input to <input `name = imei" ...` and inspect the value in the controller using `var imei = Request["imei"]`. But learn to use a view model, and bind you inputs to the values of your view model using strongly typed helpers, then change the signature of your controller methods to `public ActionResult(MyViewModel model) {..` and you wont have these problems (and your will reduce your code significantly)

Comment: Ok ive converted over the text fields of the form but i have an issue in that my span tags which display the dropdown selection cannot have a name property. how do i do the Request[] in this case?

Comment: A dropdown needs to be rendered as `<select name="SomeThing"><option value="value1">Item 1</option><option value="value2">Item 2</option></select>` where the value of property `SomeThing` will be either `value1` or `value2` depending on what the user selects - but all this is done with `@Html.DropDownListFor()`. You really need to start working through a few basic MVC tutorials before you go any further

Comment: Ive seen this method of creating a drop down before and i will try to convert my dropdowns,but I'm now confused isn't the version you suggest a standard html dropdown? essentially an un-styled version of a bootstrap dropdown? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Your confusing html (the markup that renders elements) and css (which determines how the elements look). All your need to do is apply the relevant class name `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YourProperty, Model.YourSelectList, new { @class = "form-control"})` Learn the basics first.

Comment: Thank you for your time & explanations Stephen, I will go back and do some more tutorials before carrying on with my project.